# projection and multiple level eagerly loading issue on EF6

Tags: entity-framework, eager-loading

im using EF6 and im having an issue projectin into anonymus type on multiple level  eagerly loading: this is an example:

```
 var scheduledList = db_hms.Scheduled
                    .Include(s => s.scheduled_product_service.Select(sps => sps.Product_Service))
                    .Where(s => s.id_medical_doctor == idMedic)
                    .Select(sch => new
                    {
                       id_scheduled = sch.id_scheduled,
                       id_natural_person = sch.id_natural_person,
                       scheduled_product_service = sch.scheduled_product_service,
                       obs = sch.obs,
                    }).ToList();
```

so scheduled_product_service is a list and `Product_Service` is an object on that list, the problem is that when i execute this code, and then try to get the `Product_Service` i get a null exception.

any know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late but as I'm struggling with the issue now, it seems entity framework does not support eager loading along with projection. You need to load entire data into memory and then do the projection:

```
var scheduledList = db_hms.Scheduled
                .Include(s => s.scheduled_product_service.Select(sps => sps.Product_Service))
                .Where(s => s.id_medical_doctor == idMedic)
                .ToList()
                .Select(sch => new
                {
                   id_scheduled = sch.id_scheduled,
                   id_natural_person = sch.id_natural_person,
                   scheduled_product_service = sch.scheduled_product_service,
                   obs = sch.obs,
                });
```

This should work for you, but it's not optimal though!